# COMPRESS is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

According to the documentation given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I am tried to use `COMPRESS` function  to compress VARCHAR(MAX) column data before storing in SQL server, but its not working

```
SELECT COMPRESS ('Satishakumar');
```

The error I received in SSMS is

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1 'COMPRESS' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

The version details of SQL server are

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64)   Jan  5 2018 22:11:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Comment: As per the document [COMPRESS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you linked to as well: *"APPLIES TO: SQL Server (**starting with 2016**)"*. Emphasis mine. You're using 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the docs from the link you gave, this function is available in SQL Server starting with version 2016, while you are using version 2012.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part in the link, our DB version is 2012.